# Make JFace databinding revalidate

Tags: data-binding, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a dialog for entering a number of paths on the remote system. I use databindings to store those paths in my model.
My databings have validators attached that have a common trait - validation is skipped when there is no connection to a remote system. I have a button on the same dialog to connect to the remote system and I have IObservableValue that tracks connection state.

How can I make relevant bindings revalidate when connection status changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add valuechangeListener on IObservableValue that tracks connection state. Once connection state changes, call below methods to validate path bindings. this might help to get to what you are looking for

```
Binding class
public abstract void validateTargetToModel();
public abstract void validateModelToTarget();
```

Comment: I consider this way too cumbersome as I tend to move controls between wizard pages, etc. - I need to validate the model as whole. What I ended up doing is creating ComputedValue that validates the whole model and returns IStatus - and then my another custom observer updates the page header with the IStatus data. This way my validation is properly triggered when relevant values (including connection state) change.